# Integer solutions to $r\cdot a^2+t=s\cdot b^2$ forms sequences with $a_{n+1}\cdot b_n-a_n\cdot b_{n+1}$ is invariant

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations, conjectures

Conjecture:
Given natural numbers $r,s,t$. Suppose there are an infinite number of solutions $a_n,b_n \in \mathbb N$ to $ra_n^2+t=sb_n^2$, where $a_n, b_n$ correspond to increasing sequences of solutions, then $a_n\cdot b_{n+1} - a_{n+1}\cdot b_n$ is invariant equal for each $n$ greater than some $N>0$.

I've done a lot of tests without exceptions. The number $N$ is typically $\le 1$. I would like to see ideas how to proceed.

Some $(r,s,t)$ values plus sets of $(a,b)$ values:

```
(1,2,1)
{(1,1),(7,5),(41,29),(239,169),(1393,985),(8119,5741)}

(2,1,1)
{(0,1),(2,3),(12,17),(70,99),(408,577),(2378,3363)}

(1,2,2)
{(0,1),(4,3),(24,17),(140,99),(816,577),(4756,3363)}

(3,2,2) 
{(0,1),(4,5),(40,49),(396,485),(3920,4801)}

(2,3,1)
{(1,1),(11,9),(109,89),(1079,881),(10681,8721)}
```

There seems to be a matrix

$
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha & ms \\
mr & \alpha \\
\end{pmatrix}
$

that transform $(a_{n},b_{n})$ to $(a_{n+1},b_{n+1})$, but I haven't proved that and I'm insecure about $\alpha$ and $m$. It could be that $\alpha=\sqrt{m^2rs+1}$ and that the determinant is unital.

**The conjecture is false with counter-example**

```
(1,2,7)
{(1,2),(5,4),(11,8),(31,22),(65,46),(181,128),(379,268)}
```

**What's left is**
Given $r,s,t\in\mathbb R_+$ and $S=\{(a,b)\in\mathbb R_+^2|rs^2+t=sb^2\}$, then it exist a sequence $(a_n,b_n)\in S$ such that:
$$a_{n+1}b_n-a_nb_{n+1}=2t \tag 1$$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{n+1} \\
b_{n+1} \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt{4rs+1}& 2s \\
2r & \sqrt{4rs+1} \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_n\\
b_n \\
\end{pmatrix}
\tag 2$$
which I consider as virtually proved by the accepted answer.

Comment: Some example values of $r,s,t$ & how they work out, would be nice to see. You of course know this will be related to integer solutions of the Pell equation, might want to mention this in your question. Indeed the solution probably lies in the continued fraction of $\sqrt{r/s}$.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit - I've filled in with some context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a,b$ solve the equations and let $\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha & s \\
r & \alpha \\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a \\b\\\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}A \\B\\\end{pmatrix}$ with $\alpha$ as in your post and $m=1$.

Then straightforward algebra shows that $A,B$ also solve the equation.

Then $Ab-aB=(\alpha a+sb)b-a(ra+\alpha b)=sb^2-ra^2=t$, as you require.

Note. The above proof does not assume anything about the integer nature of the parameters. One can multiply each of $r,s,t$ by any number $m$ say and obtain the corresponding result. In that case the invariant value will of course be $mt$.

I assume that is what you you are interested in and that you will wish to choose $m$ so that $(m,\alpha)$ is an integer solution of the Pell equation $$(rs)x^2+1=y^2.$$

Furthermore, so as not to 'miss' solutions, $(m,\alpha)$ should be the fundamental solution.

Comment: You have shown that the linear system implies the relation.

Comment: Is there something else you require?

Comment: The conjecture. My matrix represents a generalized example.

Comment: m=2, but your trick works.